# What should I write as affiliated institute?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, authorship

I have been accepted into college but have not yet started. The research I did was done before I was accepted into college. So should I add the college as the affiliated institute or not?

Comment: @Coder edit has been made. Thanks for pointing out. I have been accepted but have not yet started.

Comment: The answer to your question is "NO".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your affiliation should be whatever institute you were located at *when you did your research.* Wherever you are at the time the research is presented is listed as "current affiliation" or "present address."

If you have not started or matriculated at an institution, you should **not** list it as either an actual affiliation or a present address.